# How do I create List<type> for runtime type?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have some code like this, I don't know what type is until runtime.

```
Type type;
```

And I need a list defined as:

```
List<type>
```

I've tried

```
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new []{type});

IList list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType));
```

But it does not work well because I need to pass this list to XmlSerializer.Serialize method.  **It only output a correct result when this list is defined exactly List**

for example:
When I pass in

`List<String> list = new List<String>()`

It output

```
<ArrayOfString>...</ArrayOfString>
```

When I pass in

`IList list = new List<String>()`

It will output

```
<ArrayOfAnyType>...</ArrayOfAnyType>
```

which is not what I want.

How can I define a List when I don't know what type is at compile time?

Comment: Not sure I actually understand the problem. But if you want a list, can you just call a ToList() to convert your collection to a list? Assuming activator.createInstance returns some IEnumerable... var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType).ToList();

Comment: Your title and tags are really not correct for your question. You seem to be able to make a run-time `List<>` type correctly. You are really having trouble with run-time types and the `XMLSerializer`. You might get better answers with a better title and better tags.

Comment: What type are you passing to the constructor of `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: I haven't actually realized the problem is how people initialize XmlSerializer because it was in a class created long ago.  Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're creating the serialiser with:

```
var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IList));
```

you should pass the real list type:

```
var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());
```

Note the following works as expected:

```
var t = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string));
var list = (System.Collections.IList)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
list.Add("string1");
list.Add("string2");

var serialiser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(list.GetType());
var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
serialiser.Serialize(writer, list);

var result = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```